# Java boolean int comparable

Tags: java, command, boolean

hi can anyone tell me why this isn't working or point me in the right direction all i am trying to do is take a users input of 3 numbers compare them if they are the same which would be 3 of a kind or whether they are all different which would make it all different or if it is a run of 1 2 3 etc

error code i get is incomparable types boolean and int

```
public boolean different() {

 do {
   System.out.println ("All results are different" + "\n" + rollone + "\n" + 
        rolltwo + "\n" + rollthree);
  }

  while (rollone != rolltwo && != rollthree) ;     

}
```

any ideas much appreciated in advance

Comment: Review basic java syntax.

Comment: The `!=` operator (like any binary operator) requires two operands at all times, one on the left, one on the right.

Comment: Also, your method *must* return a boolean value.

Comment: Also, if you need to make sure all three values are different, you will need three `!=` operators; two won't be enough.  Also, the above code is likely to print out your message an infinite number of times.  You probably don't want to print the output repeatedly; just what **is** it that you want to do more than once?  That's what will need to go inside the body of the loop.

Comment: Basically all i want to do is take 3 user inputs as an integer, compare the three integers to see if they are 3 of a kind, 2 numbers are the same or they are a run of 3 but not sure what lines to go along here... whether to use a while loop or if and else stataments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this would be a set of if statements. Usage of a do/while loop is a bit confusing in your example code. I would start by breaking up the logic into multiple parts. So for example: Let's say I want to know if a number is even or odd.

What would I normally do if I didn't know how to tell if a number was even or odd just by looking at it? Well, I know that any number that's a multiple of 2 is even. And anything that isn't is odd. How can I translate that into code?

```
if(x % 2 == 0) { return true; }
```

This is using the modulo operator. It's essentially, "Given that I have the number x, what remains if I divide it by 2?" If this is 0, x is divisible by 2. Ergo, even.

```
else { return false; }
```

If it's not even, it must be odd. Simple stuff.

Now for your problem, you've described a lot of use cases. I would say write down each use case and try to think of the logic in your mind of how -you- would manually do it. (i.e. Someone hands you 3 numbers on pieces of paper. How would determine if they were the same? If they were a run? If they had no relationship?) And then think of how you can apply that logic with if / else statements.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks! i'm just not sure how to eliminate the incomparable types error!

Comment: You should be comparing the three integers, but not on the same line. So.. 1 != 2 <- returns a boolean. so when you do 1 != 2 (boolean) != 3 (int) you're doing an incorrect comparison. You may want to break it up into multiple if / else's